# VBA range with possible gap in range

Tags: vba, excel, range

When I try to combine ranges in a single column but with a gap in between, it resume next due to something wrong with the code. Below is the code I've been trying to run:

```
Set Rrng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet9.Name).Range("D14:D19").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

If Not IsEmpty(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet9.Name).Range("D21")) Then

    Set Rrng = Union(Rrng, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet9.Name).Range("D20:D22").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))

End If

If Not IsEmpty(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet9.Name).Range("D24")) Then

    Set Rrng = Union(Rrng, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet9.Name).Range("D23:D25").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))

End If

If Not IsEmpty(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet9.Name).Range("D27")) Then

    Set Rrng = Union(Rrng, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet9.Name).Range("D26:D28").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))

End If

Set Rrng = Union(Rrng, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet9.Name).Range("D29:D" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
```

I guess this should be fixed with reffering to cells instead, but I'm not sure?

Comment: *it resume next due to something wrong with the code.* - can you be more specific about your problem? Which line of code does not work or does not do what you expect it to? Or what is the result you expect versus what you get? As it stands, your code looks pretty good.

Comment: Let's assume the first IF function is not empty, while the remaining two IF functions is empty. Under this assumption, the Rrng should be `.range("D19:D22","D29:D"&lastrow)`, however it skips to next counter when it gets to the last row in the above code.

Comment: so it doesn't process the line where you Union  `.Range("D29:D" & LastRow`? Did you step through the code line-by-line to prove this? And do you have any `On Error Resume Next` statements in your code that you did not redirect back to `On Error GoTo 0`?

Comment: When I step through it line-by-line the following is happening in the example I gave in above comment: Row 1 give Rrng the value2 from `.range("D14:D19")`. The first If function (Not Empty) give Rrng the Value2 `.range("D14:D22")`. If function 2 & 3 (Is Empty), and the value2 stays the same, however when it runs the last row in the code, it does not add `.range("D29:D & LastRow")`. Compared to 2 min ago, it does not `On Error Resume Next` but continue to next line.

Comment: sorry, its still confusing to me your **exact** problem. So, it does not error out on the line `Set Rrng = Union(Rrng, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet9.Name).Range("D29:D" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))`, but it also does not add the `Range("D29:D" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` to `Rrng`?

Comment: if you `debug.print` on `Rrng.Address` right after it passes that line, what do you get?

Comment: FYI: if all three if cases is not empty it works. the address is as follows (which is correct): `$D$14:$D$22,$D$29:$D$32`. The full code copies the range into Outlook Email, but it will not do it, unless all three If statements are not empty.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. The code works for me as is and prints the correct addresses for each scenario I tested. Whether 1, 2, or 3 of the conditions are empty or not. One thing I can think of is that a cell may appear `blank` but not actually be `empty`? Maybe try `Len(cell) = 0` or `cell.value2 = ""` instead of `IsEmpty`.

Answer (score 0):

Is there something that prevents you to simply use

```
set rRng = range("d14:d" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
```

?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that LastRow is a row number obtained from some Range reference (for example: `lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet9.Name).Range("D65536").end(xlUp).Row`)
, this will be an integer, however referencing cells like this requires a string variable. Hence it should be typecast as follows:

`Set Rrng = Union(Rrng, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet9.Name).Range("D29:D" & CStr(LastRow)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))`

Comment: DV - a `String` literal is **not** required in this statement.

Comment: This does not change the situation. Also, I've tried to put in D32 (which in this case is the lastrow) instead of lastrow, and it does not change anything.

Comment: Are there any visible cells in Range("D29:D32") at all? If not, you're trying to union a Range with a non-existent range. VBA will throw error 1004 if you try to set a Range object to a range without cells in it.